# Passing message from content script in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

I want to run a content script to identify the first image that links somewhere and return the link to the background script. But I can't pass any messages between them, and I don't know why. Much of the code is comment, I'm trying to simply test if the content script is executing by telling it to change the first header to "test" (since the only thing I can do without messages is change a page's HTML and CSS). The code follows:
EDIT: full updated code

Background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs)
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file:"content.js"}, function ()
    {
        console.log("sending first time");
        console.log(tabs[0].id);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{test: "test"}, function (response)
        {
            if (undefined == response)
            {
                console.log ("first one didn't work");
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {test: "test"}, function (response)
                {
                    console.log(response.test);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

Content Script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function (msg, sender, sendResponse)
{
/*var test1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
test1.innerHTML="test";*/
sendReponse({test: "123"});
/*var parentList =document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var link = "";
var child;
for (var i=2; i<parentList.length;i++)
{
    child=parentList[i].firstChild;
    if ("IMG"==child.nodeName)
    {
        link=parentList[i].href;
        break;
    }
}
teste1.innerHTML=link;
var answer = new Object();
Answer.link = link;
teste1.innerHTML=answer.link;
sendResponse({messager:answer});*/
});
```

Comment: It could be the issue is related to the dom manipulation, not the message. Why not try executing the sendResponse callback from the contentscript, and in the background script, console.log the response.

Comment: Also, have you checked the tabs error console? I believe errors or console.logs from the contentscript will show up there.

Comment: To levi: Even if I put a simple statement like an alert, if it is inside chrome.tabs.querry, it won't execute. Also, I cannot write to the console. That's another issue for which I opened another question.

Comment: Updating the situation: Thanks to levi's post in my other question regarding the console, I could see a syntax error in my background script. Now commands anywhere on the background script execute normally. Only the content script is giving trouble.

Comment: As per the docs - `The argument should be any JSON-ifiable object`. Try sending an object

Comment: I tried. A runtime error ocurred; he said he couldn't find member of "unidentified"

Comment: Please post your full updated code

Comment: @levi posted it some days ago. Are you also stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing the extension at the extension page itself. But it seems you can't inject javascript in it (probably because it is a browser's settings page). It worked nicely on other pages.